# I want to stick a div left to another div

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am working for this website's responsiveness, 
I want to stick the ratings image left to with a bit margin, when the width of the window is 335 it is working on left: 50% but when i increase the width of the window, it doesn't remain stick to what i want, Please suggest me, what should i do ??

Here is my code

```
<div id="filteredRestBody" class="row filteredRestBody">
  <div id="row1" class="row">
     <div id="yochina" class="col-sm-4 filterThumbnails" style="background: url('images/yochinathumbbck.jpg')">
     <img src="images/bestoffers.png">
     <div id="discountImg">
     <img src="images/discountimg.png" style="">
     <div class="discountNum" title="Discount">15%</div>
 </div>
 <div id="ratings" title="6/10">
     <img src="images/ratingy.png">
     <img src="images/ratingy.png">
     <img src="images/ratingy.png">
     <img src="images/ratingy.png">
     <img src="images/ratingy.png">
     <img src="images/ratingw.png">
     <img src="images/ratingw.png">
     <img src="images/ratingw.png">
     <img src="images/ratingw.png">
     <img src="images/ratingw.png">
 </div>
 <div id="ratingNum">5</div>
 <div id="restaurantThumbnailsTitle" class="restaurantThumbnailsTitle">
    <span><a href="viewRestaurant.php?rest=yochina">Yo! China</a></span>
    <br>
    <span class="restaurantThumbnailsTitleText">chilled out chinese</span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.filteredRestBody {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: medium none;
    border-top-left-radius: 23px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 grey;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: -4%;
    padding: 0 0 47px 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    width: 111%;
}

.filterThumbnails {
    background-position: 2px -19px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top-left-radius: 10%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 5.3%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -36px;
    width: auto;
}

#ratings {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0 7px 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
}

#ratingsNum {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 193, 0, 0.9);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    left: 89%;
    padding: 0 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45.5%;
    width: auto;
}
```

[This is the first screenshot when the width is 335](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9TwkofAKcEfT1N5VGdZdnBCakU&authuser=0)

[This is what happens when i increase the window's width](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9TwkofAKcEfaE9CclU5cHBqTE0&authuser=0)

Comment: So if I get it correctly, you want both ratings and ratingNum to be always aligned on right, with a margin between stars and numeric value. Is it right?

Comment: exactly, that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `left`, you can use `right` property in your CSS. This will stick `ratingsNum` and `ratings` divs to the right border of container div.

**CSS**

```
#ratings {
  right:50px;
}

#ratingsNum {
  right:10px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kquLf0gm/)**

Hope it helps.

As a side note, I've noticed that your snippet contains some elements (i.e. `#discountImg` div) without the closing tag (in this example `</div>`). Pay attention because this can lead your layout to unpredictable results.

Comment: It worked out by doing position relative and float right and adjusting some positions, Anyway, thank you Giorgio for your answer